# In-game logic for why Eldritch Blast affects constructs but does not affect inanimate objects?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage

I've not yet been asked this by my players as none of them have yet tried to use it on an object, but if they do, I want to understand the properties of the energy and method of damage of Eldritch Blast, and why it can only affect creatures, as I don't want to be a DM who explains things as "it just does, because the book says so".

Why does Eldritch Blast not affect inanimate objects, but can affect machine-creatures or objects animated by magic?

Comment: How is 'Why does eldritch blast affect creatures but not objects'? an opinion based question? I'm asking what the properties of the spell are.

Comment: I am inclined to agree that the question itself is not primarily opinion-based, but I can also see the rationale for closing, since the *answers* “will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise”. Sometimes good questions get closed because the answers promise to be badly behaved. :-/ Either way, I'm leaving this to others to fight out with close/reopen votes because I can see both sides (and my conflict of interest of being an answerer shouldn't break that tie).

Comment: @Sent_ Please don't try to go around a hold by using comments to post an answer. If you have an answer, work to get the question reopened instead.

Answer (score 9):

There is no existing explicit in-game justification for the reason. Like many parts of the game, this is up to you, the DM, to explain if it needs explaining.

The explanation could be all kinds of things, limited only by the DM's imagination. For example:

- The spell's arcane design — as laboriously encoded in the spell's writing and expressed in the vocal, somatic, and material components — relies on the presence of a creature in order to function correctly. (How does magic tell creatures from non-creatures? Magic!)
- The “crackling energy” is never described in further detail. Maybe this energy can only connect to something with a life-force, or its nature is such that it only affects life-force.

There are as many possible explanations as there are DMs to invent them. Put your stamp on your campaign and make this spell your own, by choosing an explanation that enriches your particular game world.

Or, as with many DM decisions, you can recruit your players to contribute to the details of the world. “Hmm, I don't know why it only affects creatures. Hey Warlock, why do you think that is?”

Comment: Agree 100%.  My personal reason would be that Eldritch Blast is a magcal force that functions by withering / wearing down the life force of any creatures it contacts.  Constructs and animated objects are imbued with a magical "life force" that is similar enough to natural living beings that the spell can affect them equally.  basically anything animate is fair game, while anything inanimate is immune.

Answer (score 3):

**I would tie the Eldritch Blasts Force damage to the target's source plane.**

To tie it in to why it can affect magical constructs and animated objects through spells, I would justify that the Eldritch Blast is affecting the source or link to the plane which is powering the object. So if you were targeting a character, you would be affecting their essence / soul. If you are targeting a construct, you would be targeting the thread of magic and weakening it's effect on the construct, thereby "damaging" it (this is actually how I deal with all construct damage since animated things don't have pain receptors and thereby don't have health. Instead, I make it so that damage weakens the magical hold on the construct until the link is severed.)

This makes Eldritch Blast a weapon that transcends the material plane, which is at the very least suggested within the framework of the planes of D&D. Considering the damage type for Eldritch Blast is Force, and Force is the one damage type that can actually transcend planes (for example a creature in the Ethereal Plane can be damaged by Force spells from the Material Plane). This is what makes it seem logically consistent to me.

Much more information on the planes and the Ethereal plane can be found starting on DMG pg. 43, and the ability for magical Force to damage creatures on the Ethereal plane from a different plane are on DMG pg. 48 under the Border Ethereal portion.